# Who is the underlined square k certification

Tags: kashrut-kosher, food

I recently noticed that some Ronzoni pasta does not have the OU as in the past. Instead it has the underlined square k. Does anyone know which certifying agency this is? [image]

Comment: Is it just oven ready lasagna? That's precooked so may have always been a different certification

Comment: I have oven ready boxes in my house with the OU and on Ronzoni website it says the oven ready pasta is certified by the OU

Comment: The OU website says the oven ready Ronzoni pasta is certified under the OU so long the OU is on the box. Valid until end of January 2020.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's [1K Kosher](http://www.1kosher.org), under the supervision of R' Menahem Hadad in Brussels, Belgium. They are listed on R' Eydlitz's [KosherQuest](http://kosherquest.org) as reliable, although CYLOR.